# How can I use Powershell to keep two directories updated with the latest files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two directories:

```
C:\G\admin\less
C:\G\user\less
```

Inside of those directives I have multiple less and css files. I know all the names of the files so I would like to hardcode a list of these into the script. Perhaps this could be in an array or something but my knowledge of PowerShell is not even enough to know if there are arrays in the scripting language.

```
C:\G\admin\less

html-light.less
html-light.css
html-dark.less
html-dark.css
do-not-track-me.less

C:\G\user\less

html-light.less
html-light.css
html-dark.less
html-dairk.css
do-not-track-me.less
```

Is there a way I can use PowerShell to check each of these files (that I want to hardcode in my program) one by one and copy the last modified file from its directory to the other directory so that both directories will contain the same latest versions of these files?

Note that I would need to evaluate the predefined list of files one by one. Comparing modified date in one directory with the other and copying over as needed.

Comment: I thought you just stated that they *don't change*?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think she means the file *names* don't change.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use `robocopy`.

Comment: So which directory has the newer files?

Comment: Either directory could have the newer files.  For my needs I have say 20 known files in both directories.  I am okay with hardcoding those 20 into a powershell script.  What I would need is a script that could check each of those files in directory a and directory b and if one file has a modified date greater than the other I need that file to be copied to the other directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

again assume that this isn't the best solution or approach 
This solution assumes following 
 - when the LastWriteTime on one folder is bigger than the other it copy it to another folder. 
 - I'm not doing the path validation because of laziness but if you want with path validation just ask. 
 - I'm assuming that all the files on those folder must be tracked otherwise read the comment on code.
 - i suggest you backup your folder before you run the script.

```
#if there is a file you don't want to track on those folder (for example you don't want to track txt files) 
#just  write $userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\ -Exclude "*.txt"
#if you don't want track txt but only one of them should be track among with other file format
#$userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\ -Exclude "*.txt" -Include "C:\G\user\less\Txtadditionaltotrack.txt"
$userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\
$adminfiles=dir C:\G\admin\less\
foreach($userfile in $userFiles)
{
   $exactadminfile= $adminfiles | ? {$_.Name -eq $userfile.Name} |Select -First 1
   #my suggestion is to validate if it got the file.
   #By now because of my lazy i will not call the test-path to validate if it got the file
   #I'm assuming all directory are exact copy of each other so it will find the file.

  if($exactadminfile.LastWriteTime -gt $userfile.LastWriteTime)
  {
    Write-Verbose "Copying  $exactadminfile.FullName to $userfile.FullName "
    Copy-Item -Path $exactadminfile.FullName -Destination $userfile.FullName -Force
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Verbose "Copying  $userfile.FullName to $exactadminfile.FullName "
    Copy-Item -Path $userfile.FullName -Destination $exactadminfile.FullName -Force
  }
}
```

you can improve it because the way this code is it always copy file from one directory to another inside the else you can validate so that when the lastwriteTime is equal on both it doesn't copy.
You can improve it in many ways.  i hope you got the ideia

Find the modification made to code so that it can archieve this requirement.
PLEASE READ THE COMMENT IN CODE. 
NOTE  THAT I'M NOT FOLLOWING THE BEST PRATICE (avoid unexpected error, name correctly all variable, ...)

```
#to make it more dynamical you can save on one file
#all the file names including extension in different lines.
#For example on path C:\FilesToWatch\watcher.txt
#$filestowatch=get-content C:\FilesToWatch\watcher.txt

$filestowatch="felicio.txt","marcos.txt"
$userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\
$adminfiles=dir C:\G\admin\less\

#Optionally instead of use this if approach you can 

#$userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\ |? {$filestowatch -contains $_.Name}
#$adminfiles=dir C:\G\admin\less\|? {$filestowatch -contains $_.Name}

#loading in the above manner the first if statement on code bellow can be removed because 
#We make sure that $userFiles and $adminfiles only have correct file to monitor

foreach($userfile in $userFiles)
{
   if($filestowatch -contains $userfile.Name)
   {
      $exactadminfile= $adminfiles | ? {$_.Name -eq $userfile.Name} |Select -First 1
       #my suggestion is to validate if it got the file.
       #By now because of my lazy i will not call the test-path to validate if it got the file
       #I'm assuming all directory are exact copy of each other so it will find the file.

      if($exactadminfile.LastWriteTime -gt $userfile.LastWriteTime)
      {
         Write-Verbose "Copying  $exactadminfile.FullName to $userfile.FullName "
         Copy-Item -Path $exactadminfile.FullName -Destination $userfile.FullName -Force
       }
       else
       {
          Write-Verbose "Copying  $userfile.FullName to $exactadminfile.FullName "
          Copy-Item -Path $userfile.FullName -Destination $exactadminfile.FullName -Force
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Felicio. I have some files in the directory that I want to do this to and others not.  Can I somehow make a list of the files and put these in the powershell code. so it does not do foreach and pick all files?

Comment: Yes you can there is many ways to do one off the ways is int the code comment  $userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\ -Exclude "*.txt" -Include "C:\G\user\less\Txtadditionaltotrack.txt"


you can add all your files separated by comman in include parameter or you can pipe your dir command with where clause. do you know how to??

Comment: @SamanthaJ can you check the new approach? and then give a feedback

Comment: Thank you Felicio.  I will check this in the next 24 hours and then let you know.  I think it looks like just what I need. If I wanted to run this do I put it in a file ending in .ps1?

Comment: Yes save it with .ps1 extension. assuming you want to run with double click, create one batch file open notepad and paste following code without quotes.

"powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\yourfile.ps1"

and save with bat extension. then just double click. 

first I suggest you to copy and paste into powershell console just to see it working. if it's ok. you can follow the procedure on this comments

Make sure your bat file and your ps1 file are on same directory.

Comment: I did everything you suggested but I think there's a problem and I don't see any output because the command window opens and then closes quick. Is there a way I can make the command window stay open. Is there a way I can debug this so I see the messages or errors ?

Comment: First try to open the powershell copy and paste the code above. And see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is symbolic links, aka symlinks.

With symlinks, you can define files and folders that will be always in-sync, where the target file is updated automatically when the original is modified.

To create a symbolic link, enter the following in the console/command prompt:

`mklink /[command] [link path] [file or folder path]`

Mklink can create several types of links, according to these commands:

- **/D** – creates a soft symbolic link, which is similar to a standard folder or file shortcut in Windows. This is the default option, and mklink will use it if you do not enter a command.
- **/H** – creates a hard link to a file.
- **/J** – creates a hard link to a folder.

The syntax is simple. Choose your option, define the path you want for the symlink, and finally the path of the original file/folder.

For example, imagine I'm developing a new project, and I want to share it to my client via Dropbox shared folder. I don't want to move all my workspace to dropbox, I just want to share that specific folder to them:

`mklink /J C:\Dropbox\clients_shared_folders\project_x C:\my_dev_rootfolder\project_x`

Note that the first path is the symbolic folder I want to create, while the second path is the existing directory.

In you case, I'll be assuming your working on the *admin* folder, and want to generate a syncd copy on the *user* folder:

`mklink /J C:\G\user\less C:\G\admin\less`

Here's a nice article for more info:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: Creating a symbolic link means that you only have a single set of files. You're not synchronizing a user folder from a master. Any change to the user folder directly affects the master.

Comment: Thank you for your advice however I do need a script that I can run as during development I may not work on one file and then at a later time want to push that over to the other folder.

Comment: Symlinks only need to be defined once. They'll remain active until you remove the symlink. But I see wat you mean - you don't want to break the master code when saving.